# write the contents of the python script in the log

Tags: python

Let's say I have a script `script.py` that looks like this:

```
# script.py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    filename='log.log',
    filemode='w', # new log everytime
    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
)

logging.logging('Sample log')
```

What I want to see in `log.log` is:

```
2020/03/18 09:23:00 PM Sample log
# yes this is a new line
'''
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    filename='log.log',
    filemode='w', # new log everytime
    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
)

logging.logging('Sample log')
'''
```

So I have the actual log, and at the end of it, the contents of the script that was run. Is this possible?

Comment: You may be interested by the module `inspect`.

Comment: The answer you currently have won't always work -- in some environments or scenarios (depending on how your program is installed), you might not even have the `.py` file at all, but may be running off a `.pyc` or `.pyo`, perhaps themselves inside a zip file or other container format. More robust answers that work off the AST are possible, though they won't include comments or precise formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `atexit` module and at the end of your program, open the current file and write its contents into the logger.

To get the current filename, you can run

```
import pathlib
this_file = __file__
```

and then open the file and read it into a string

```
with open(this_file, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
```

and finally,

```
logging.info("\n'''{}\n'''".format(data))
```

So your whole code could be

```
import atexit

def log_script_contents(filepath):
   import logging
   with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
      data = file.read()
   logging.info("\n'''{}\n'''".format(data))

this_file = __file__
atexit.register(log_script_contents, this_file)
```

Comment: Since I plan to use this for several `script.py`, I want to put `log_script_contents` into a `core.py` and just call `atexit.register(core.log_script_contents())`. In that case though, would `__file__` be `core.py` instead of `script.py`?

Comment: Edited it for my purpose. Thanks!

Comment: Whether this works depends on how your Python program is installed. It's very possible for the `.py` file to be inside an `.egg` at runtime, such that it doesn't exist on the filesystem at all.